# MVC - My form is not passing my select dropdown's selected option

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to post my dropdown values to my controller using an ajax post.  All of the form values are passing just fine except for my dropdown select list.  When I look at the select element using the browser's devtools it has the name `SortByList`.

**Model**

```
public IList<SortBy> SortByList { get; set; }

public class SortBy
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

**View Dropdown List**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FDCLSubmit", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 
"reportForm", @class = "report-form col-9" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <b class="col-2" style="padding-top: 5px;">Sort By</b>
    <select asp-for="SortByList" class="form-control col-3">
        @for (var x = 0; x < Model.SortByList.Count; x++)
        {
            <option value="@Model.SortByList[x].Text">@Model.SortByList[x].Text</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
(saveSubmit button partial view here)
}
```

**Ajax Post**

```
$('#saveSubmit').on('click', function (evt) {
    var report = $('form').serialize();
    var form = new Object();
    form.report = report;
    form.EnteredCriteriaName = $('#EnteredCriteriaName').val();

    //Ajax form post
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.report,
        contentType: dataType,
        url: '@Url.Action("FDCLCheckIfExists", "Reports")',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.exists == true) {
                //Toggle the error modal and display messages
                $('#existsModal').modal('toggle');
                $('#modalYes').on('click', function () {
                    //User selected to replace report criteria
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: form.report,
                        contentType: dataType,
                        url: '@Url.Action("SaveFDCLCriteria", "Reports")',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if (data.success) {
                                window.location.href = data.url;
                            } else {
                                //Toggle the error modal and display messages
                                $('#errorsModal').modal('toggle');
                                //Add <br> tags when there is a linebreak in the string.  This will add the line breaks into the HTML.
                                $('#errorsModal .modal-body p').html(data.message.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>'));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

I set my breakpoint in this controller, and this is where the `SortByList` property of my `report` comes up as null.

```
public ActionResult FDCLCheckIfExists(FirstDollarCreditListing report, string EnteredCriteriaName)
{
    var criteria = report.ConvertToCriteria(report);
    criteria.CriteriaName = EnteredCriteriaName;
    var rep = new ReportFirstDollarCreditListing();
    var exists = rep.DoesCriteriaNameAlreadyExist(criteria);
    return Json(new { exists = exists });
}
```

Comment: you should post all form in cshtml file

Comment: where is the form element in your html? can't find it and there is no way to know if what you are retrieving from jquery is what you should send

Comment: I am avoiding posting the entire form because it is pretty long, but I've added in the form creation helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to know when you use `$('form').serialize()` it would pass data like:

```
SortByList=aaa
```

But SortByList in your model is a List,it needs the data like:

```
SortByList[0]=aaa
```

Here is a working demo:

1.Model(You need to add a property to receive the selected item):

```
public class FirstDollarCreditListing
{
    public string SelectedSort { get; set; }
    public IList<SortBy> SortByList { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

**Note**:When you use `.serialize()`, it generates the data in a 'query string' format which needs to be sent using the default contentType which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, not as JSON.

```
@model FirstDollarCreditListing
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <b class="col-2" style="padding-top: 5px;">Sort By</b>
        <select asp-for="SelectedSort" class="form-control col-3">
            @for (var x = 0; x < Model.SortByList.Count; x++)
            {
                <option value="@Model.SortByList[x].Text">@Model.SortByList[x].Text</option>
            }
        </select>        
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="saveSubmit" type="button" value=" submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<input id="EnteredCriteriaName" value="asd" />
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $('#saveSubmit').on('click', function (evt) {
        var report = $('form').serialize();

        var EnteredCriteriaName = $('#EnteredCriteriaName').val();

        //Ajax form post
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data:report+"&EnteredCriteriaName="+EnteredCriteriaName,
            url: '@Url.Action("FDCLCheckIfExists", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {
                 //..
            }
    });
});
</script>
}
```

3.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void FDCLCheckIfExists(FirstDollarCreditListing report, string EnteredCriteriaName)
{
    //...   
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: A very detailed answer. Thanks!